# How to edit an already existing cron schedule in quartz.net?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, crontrigger

I have this requirement where the schedules created earlier could be edited later. Currently what I am doing is I am deleting the previous schedule and creating a new one. But in this way, start time is giving a problem. Since the schedule start time is on a past date the schedule doesn't fire. Even when I increase the existing to start time to a time in future, still schedule doesn't fire. What is the best to way to have a feature that would let users edit existing schedules? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [RescheduleJob](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/?topic=html/9357a177-7bb1-5d4a-c2ad-9ef279427159.htm) on the scheduler to reschedule it.